# Is there a term describing an almost-group without closure?

Tags: group-theory

(Background: I'm working on a dissertation in music theory that involves group theory in a small way, but it's mostly out of my element.)

I'm working with the group $\mathbb{Z}_8$, but I'm wondering what would happen if this weren't a cyclic group. In particular, I want to work with the set $\{0,1,\ldots,7\}$ but in such a way that 7 + 1 does *not* equal 0...it's undefined.

Is there some mathematical construction such that the set $\{-7,-6,\ldots,6,7\}$ can act on the integers 0-7 under addition in a way that makes sense? The integers -7 through 7 under addition are still associative and have an identity, but are not closed. I want to be able to say that $6-3=3$, but that $2-3$ is undefined.

It seems like something like an external binary operation might be of some use, but I'm not entirely sure.

**Edit**: Thanks for the groupoid suggestion. I'm not entirely clear whether or not this situation is one (all I know about the topic comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid_%28category_theory%29)). It seems to me that it isn't: the partial function is a mapping from $G \times G$ (partially) into $G$. The set $\{0,1,\ldots,7\}$ would be a groupoid under addition, but then it isn't possible to do (say) $7 \mapsto 3$. Do I have this more or less right?

I was wondering if there was a structure such that there was a set $K$ that maps $G \times K \to G$ (where $G$ is the integers 0-7 and $K$ the integers -7 through 7 inclusive, under addition).

Comment: You're looking for a _groupoid_, i.e., a "defective" group which, informally, has the binary operation replaced by a partial function.

Comment: @SQRT2: I don't think the OP's example is a groupoid.

Comment: @SQRT2 I added an edit that I hope clarifies things a bit.

Comment: @SQRT2: I also object to the description of a groupoid as being a "defective" group... in fact the theory of groupoids is in many ways much better behaved than the theory of groups.

Comment: The [definition in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid_%28category_theory%29#Algebraic) seems fairly close, but indeed not quite right: The OP seems to want a (partial) operation on _two_ sets `+ : [-7,7] × [0,7] → [0,7]` **Associativity** says there that since 6+1 and 1+1 are defined, so should 7+1=(6+1)+1 be. **Inverse** fails because `-7 ∉ [0,7]`.

Comment: I am intrigued by the music theory angle – do you have a link to tell us more? Does $Z_8$ have to do with the octave (though that is mod 7, 12 or oodles)?

Comment: @PJTraill The example I'm working with is a little esoteric, but you're right that the octave is mod 7 or 12. The idea is called [transformational theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_theory), but the space I'm working with is bounded. Imagine trying to describe intervals on a [Little Tikes piano](http://duniabermain.com/uploads/wpsc/product_images/12.Little%20Tikes%20TAp%20a%20Tune%20Piano.JPG)—it's not meaningful to go 2 notes up from red or a note below purple, but the set `[-7,7]` contains all possible intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be covered by the notion of a [local group](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/notes-on-local-groups/). This gets used sometimes in additive combinatorics. But what precise sets of axioms you want depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Your reference defines a local group as a topological space with extra structure, which sounds more complicated than the OP wants.

Comment: @PJTraill: of course you can specialize to the case that the topology is discrete. I linked to that post because I'm not aware of another reference.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the suggestion; I'll look into it (though I don't know much at all about topology).

Comment: @Michael: you don't need to know anything about topology (in your case the local group is finite and carries the discrete topology), but again, the precise set of axioms you want depends on what you want to do with them. If you aren't planning on proving a theorem or anything then it's unclear that you need to care about the distinctions between the various possible ways of formalizing the notion of a group with a partially defined multiplication.